# A specific drawing field in a viewcontroller - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, view

I am making an application where the user sign an form with their signature (analog, with stylus) and I am having this code:

In .h:

```
 CGPoint lastPoint;
    CGPoint movebackTo;
    CGPoint currentPoint;
    CGPoint location;
    NSDate *lastClick;
    BOOL mouseSwiped;
    UIImageView *drawImage;
```

And in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
drawImage.image = [preferences objectForKey:@"drawImageKey"];
drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([touch tapCount] == 3) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
    }

    location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastClick = [NSDate date];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 0;

    [super touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(768, 1024));
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    [drawImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];

    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
}
```

The problem is, this works fine if I want to use the WHOLE screen for drawing. But I want to use a specific part of the view as "drawing box. I already tried things like changing the line: `[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];` to `CGRectMake(58, 623, 240, 143)];` Which is the size and position the box has to be, but this is not working for me.

What happens when i change those kind of things: i can draw in the leftcorner of the view, but the actual lines display in the right box! But the drawing, plus the displaying of the code has to be in the box which is located at: X-58 y-623 and is W240 and H143.

I've searched the whole web for this specific thing but I could not find a good answer for this.

I hope you guys can help me out! It would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Why don't you use a subview for that specific part where you want to draw and calculate your points relative to that subview?

Comment: Apologise me if i'm wrong, but in a subview of type UIView, i have no ViewDidLoad, so where do i have to paste that code? @AyanSengupta

Comment: Just create a subclass of `UIView` and set the that as the class for the subview. Then, implement you touch code and override `drawInRect` method of the subclass...as simple as that! And by the way, you don't need any separate `UIImageView` to show the signature. `UIView` can manage that with `drawInRect` overridden.

Comment: I get 1 error, xCode is saying: Property "view" not found on object of type "UIView (acutally my classname "draw")", do I have to change this to viewBaselinelayout? @AyanSengupta

Comment: Are you using something like `self.view` in your `UIView` subclass? Please not that the subclass represents a view by itself and not a view controller.

Comment: I am using code like [self.view addSubview:drawImage], but that self.view does not work in subviews, do you know the code I have to replace it with @AyanSengupta i tried self.windows, but this does not work as well

Comment: I apologize if I am wrong, but I think you are messing with very fundamental things of iOS programming. Just google with "painting app in iOS" and you are gonna get a lot of tutorials regarding this. Unfortunately, I don't have enough scope or time to write such a tutorial here now :(

Comment: I understand Ayan! Although, you helped me very much! It's almost working the way i want to! @AyanSengupta